# HTML Parse and set default drop down list item

Tags: c#, html, parsing, dropdownbox

My code is like this:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("id", "userfile");       // <- select the file
nvc.Add("preview", "Upload");    // <- push the upload button on website
ImportUtilities.HttpUploadFile("http://www.site.com/", "image.png", "userfile", "image/png", nvc);
```

But there is also a drop down box with a lot of items and the item always selected is 'English' so as i wrote before nvc.Add("preview", "Upload") pushes the button 'Upload', i want to select this way 'Vietnamese' from the list as default too.

Here is the drop down box html code: http://s17.postimg.org/gzwoamwdb/ccc.png

Comment: Do not ever post code as image. Copy it and paste as text

Comment: Sorry my bad. However can you help me with this?

Comment: Sure, what is your problem with pasting code?

Comment: Not with pasting code, about to set the an item as default.. Can you help me?